# Error in robots.txt errors keep piling up even though it is fixed

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console

Somebody messed up our robots.txt by accidentally adding `\n` after our entire `allow: /products/` which are about 30.000 pages in total. The errors are on multiple language sites. This is one of our Search consoles.

I quickly noticed the error and deleted it. I've asked Google to verify my solution but about 3 months later the errors are still increasing. See the images below:

[image: Screenshot of Search Console]

[image: Our robots.txt]

Is there anything I can do to speed up the proces? I have started the validation.

Comment: post an url of your robots.txt

Comment: https://www.unisgroup.nl/robots.txt/

Answer (score 1):

Your robots.txt is unreachable. It is redirected by 301 to `https://www.unisgroup.nl/robots.txt/`, which is directory, not a file - do you see the trailing slash? Google is looking for a file, doesn't find it and goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So I should change the location of the robots.txt or should I change something in search console?

Comment: You should make robots.txt file reachable as file with the status code 200